# Will wise owl obfuscate wpf projects properly?

Tags: c#, wpf, obfuscation, owl, wise

We are moving from windows forms to wpf for the next version of the product I work on. We are using wise owl to do our obfuscation and I am wondering if anyone has had experience with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be done. You need to flag everything you don't want to bind to as don't obfuscate but it works.